# Valid Anagram - Could Someone Please Explain why my code doesn't pass Example Case 2?

Tags: java, arrays, hash, anagram

Given two strings s and t, return true if t is an anagram of s, and false otherwise.

An Anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters exactly once.

Example 1:
Input: s = "anagram", t = "nagaram"
Output: true

Example 2:
Input: s = "rat", t = "car"
Output: false

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
        char[] t_array = t.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(s_array);
        Arrays.sort(t_array);

        if (s_array.length == t_array.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= s_array.length-1; i++) {
                if (s_array[i] == t_array[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

For Example 2, I'm getting the output as true when the expected is false.

I believe that my code should meet the requirements of the problem, but it is not working as expected. My approach involves converting the given string into a char array, sorting it, and then comparing it with another sorted char array. I expect that if the two arrays have the same values for each index, they are anagrams. However, it seems that there is something missing or incorrect in my approach.

Comment: Your current code returns `true` immediately on a character match. You need to check **all** characters. (But see previous comment.)

Comment: Crap, I was thinking palindromes. Ignore original comment. I'm not sure which is worse--that I spaced out, or that it was still in my head 30 minutes later.

Answer (score 1):

After sorting you only have to check if the arrays are equal and return that as the result:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
        char[] t_array = t.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(s_array);
        Arrays.sort(t_array);

        return Arrays.equals(s_array,t_array);
    }
}
```

In your code you should only return false when they don't match:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
        char[] t_array = t.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(s_array);
        Arrays.sort(t_array);

        if (s_array.length == t_array.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= s_array.length-1; i++) {
                if (s_array[i] != t_array[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: :rofl: :grimace: I just realized I was thinking palindromes, not anagrams.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are short circuiting your character comparison on a match without checking the other characters and returning `true` prematurely.  You need to short circuit on a mis-match and return `false`, otherwise return `true` after the for loop completes.

But no sense reinventing the wheel on comparisons. Just use `Arrays.compare`.

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
     char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
     char[] t_array = t.toCharArray();

     Arrays.sort(s_array);
     Arrays.sort(t_array);
     return Arrays.compare(s_array,t_array) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this line of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s_array.length-1; i++) {
    if (s_array[i] == t_array[i]) {
        return true;
```

so when **rat** and **cat** are arranged you get
**act** and **art** respectively
so after comparison of the first character, i.e. **'a'**, you are returning true and not checking the remaining ones as you can see that on the comparison of second character you get false. This is your error.

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
    char[] t_array = t.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(s_array);
    Arrays.sort(t_array);

    if (s_array.length == t_array.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= s_array.length-1; i++) {
            if (s_array[i] != t_array[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope it helps.